# Change value of select input before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trim some data from a select drop-down in a form just before it is submitted. The problem is the value is turning to null instead.

```
<form>
    <select name = "test"  id = "dropdown">
        <option value = "userId_1">User 1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Submit

```
scheduleForm.submit(function (e) {    
    var user = $('#dropdown').val();
    user = user .replace(/userId_/g, '');
    $('#dropdown').val(user);
    $.ajax(..........
```

I am guessing I cannot alter the value like this?

Comment: why don't you use 1 as a value beforehand?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aq33Q/ working...??

Comment: You can not set select value to one which is not in list of option. Try to change option itself and then set select value to updated option. If you are populating select from db,trim in server side itself.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh, thank you! I wish you could. I will jsut fix it on server.

Comment: Your code is working even on submit http://jsfiddle.net/aq33Q/1/

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
scheduleForm.submit(function (e) {

        var value= $('#dropdown').val();
        $('#dropdown').val(parseInt(value.replace(/\D/g,'')));
        user = $('#dropdown').val();
        $('#dropdown').val(user);
$.ajax(..........
```

Answer (score 0):

In dropdown you can select only those options which exists in the option lists: Suppose you have a drop down with option values 2,3,4,5 then you can not set the value of the dropdown to 10. You must have 10 in the option list. Why don't you do the following:-

```
scheduleForm.submit(function (e) {    
var user = $('#dropdown').val();
user = user .replace(/userId_/g, '');
```

Now use the variable "user" in your ajax instead of the $('#dropdown').val(). I think this may help you.